# Why is hashrow() generating a different hash for the same string value?

Tags: hash, teradata

Execute the following scripts using TD14.  When I run the final SELECT, HashedField returns `F5-23-BA-34`, but HashedConstant returns `2C-30-5B-4F`.

Notice how, for the INSERT, I am qualifying the constant `No` as `constant` and then using `hashrow()` on that qualifier.  When the hashed qualifier goes in, it does so as `2C-30-5B-4F` as expected.  However, when I try to hash the field itself in the select, I get `F5-23-BA-34`.  This makes no sense to me.

```
create table mydb.mytable (
    val VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
    prehashedval byte(4)
);

insert into mydb.mytable
select 'No' constant, hashrow(constant);

select 
    hashrow(val) HashedField, 
    prehashedval, 
    hashrow('No') HashedConstant 
from mydb.mytable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same string :-)

A *string literal* is always in Unicode, which hashes differently from Latin:

```
CREATE VOLATILE  TABLE mytable (
    MyField VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
    MyField_U VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO mytable('No', 'No');

SELECT 
    HASHROW(MyField) HashedField, 
    HASHROW(TRANSLATE('No' USING unicode_to_latin)),
    HASHROW(MyField_U) HashedField_U, 
    HASHROW('No')
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: You're right!  What I am actually trying to do here is compare hash between data in a view with data in another table.  In my view, the field I am hashing is a pseudo column calculated by a CASE statement which is returning a literal string.  When I wrap the CASE statement with a TRANSLATE, the comparison works.  Good call!